# sequelize transaction - Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the SentClientRequest state

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

provided I have following update statement using `Sequelize`

```
return models.UnitPlant.findOne(
        {
            where:
            {
                id: unitPlantToUpdate.id
            },
            include: [
                { model: models.ProductType },
                { model: models.VehiclePlant, as: 'Customers' }
            ]
        })
        .then(function (unitPlantFromDb) {
            return models
                .sequelize
                .transaction(
                {
                    isolationLevel: models.sequelize.Transaction.ISOLATION_LEVELS.READ_COMMITTED
                },
                function (t) {
                    return unitPlantFromDb.update(unitPlantToUpdate, { transaction: t })
                        .then(function (unitPlantFromDb) {
                            return unitPlantFromDb.setProductType(unitPlant.ProductType.id, { transaction: t })
                        })
                        .then(function (unitPlantFromDb) {
                            return unitPlantFromDb.setCustomers(unitPlant.customerIds, { transaction: t });
                        });
                })
                .then(function (result) {
                    return output.getSuccessResult(titles.SUCCESS, validationMessages.SUCCESS_ON_UPDATE, UNIT_PLANT)
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    return output.getErrorResult(titles.ERROR_ON_UPDATE, validationMessages.ERROR_ON_UPDATE, error.message);
                });
        });
```

Noting that I have a one to many relation on `Unitplant` to `Customer`.
The code above works fine but only as long as - when updating - I either only **delete** or only **insert** to `customers`.

Whenever both happen, I get following error:

***Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the SentClientRequest state***

From the console this happens:

```
Executing (783e1de2-5013-43b9-80e9-248dca6d83e1): BEGIN TRANSACTION;
Executing (783e1de2-5013-43b9-80e9-248dca6d83e1): SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
Executing (783e1de2-5013-43b9-80e9-248dca6d83e1): UPDATE [UnitPlants] SET [expiresAt]='2016-06-22',[updatedAt]='2016-06-03 12:57:50.000 +00:00' OUTPUT INSERTED.* WHERE [id] = 15
Executing (783e1de2-5013-43b9-80e9-248dca6d83e1): UPDATE [UnitPlants] SET [ProductTypeId]=1,[updatedAt]='2016-06-03 12:57:50.000 +00:00' OUTPUT INSERTED.* WHERE [id] = 15
Executing (783e1de2-5013-43b9-80e9-248dca6d83e1): SELECT [VehiclePlant].[id], [VehiclePlant].[code], [VehiclePlant].[name], [VehiclePlant].[expiresAt], [VehiclePlant].[createdAt], [VehiclePlant].[upoCustomer], [VehiclePlant].[isExport], [VehiclePlant].[updatedAt], [UnitPlantCustomers].[createdAt] AS [UnitPlantCustomers.createdAt], [UnitPlantCustomers].[updatedAt] AS [UnitPlantCustomers.updatedAt], [UnitPlantCustomers].[UnitPlantId] AS [UnitPlantCustomers.UnitPlantId], [UnitPlantCustomers].[VehiclePlantId] AS [UnitPlantCustomers.VehiclePlantId] FROM [VehiclePlants] AS [VehiclePlant] INNER JOIN [UnitPlantCustomers] AS [UnitPlantCustomers] ON [VehiclePlant].[id] = [UnitPlantCustomers].[VehiclePlantId] AND [UnitPlantCustomers].[UnitPlantId] = 15;
Executing (783e1de2-5013-43b9-80e9-248dca6d83e1): DELETE FROM [UnitPlantCustomers] WHERE [UnitPlantId] = 15 AND [VehiclePlantId] IN (4); SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS AFFECTEDROWS;
Executing (783e1de2-5013-43b9-80e9-248dca6d83e1): INSERT INTO [UnitPlantCustomers] ([createdAt],[updatedAt],[UnitPlantId],[VehiclePlantId]) VALUES ('2016-06-03 12:57:50.000 +00:00','2016-06-03 12:57:50.000 +00:00',15,3);
Executing (783e1de2-5013-43b9-80e9-248dca6d83e1): ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

Note the **INSERT** and **DELETE** there.

Why does this happen only when I have both? And how do I tackle this problem?

As a sidenote still, the whole thing works when I **do not** use the transaction which leaves me wondering if I chose a wrong isolation level or my whole setup for the transaction is just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default tedious (the node mssql driver) only supports one concurrent request, while other db libs manage query queueing automagically. Should be fixed in sequelize version 3.22

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/5752

Comment: what version is the current stable one? I am using 2.0.0

Comment: v3 is the current stable version, and 4.0 is under development

Comment: This indeed did it, transactions are now working. Thanks!